# initializing 2d vector using only 1 line c++

Tags: c++, initialization, 2d-vector

I need to be able to **initialize** a 2D vector of int's in the **same line** in which I create it.

To be more specific, I have to create a **3x2** size 2D vector and set all of it's values to 0 using only **1 line of code**.

Is there a way this can be done without using a for loop and several lines of code?

Comment: Hint: Look at the available constructors, for the `vector`.

Comment: Is **1 line of code** critical? It sounds like what you need is **one statement**; a statement can be on more than one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> twoDimVector(3, std::vector<int>(2, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have small 2d vectors (like as you suggested) it can be achieved (using [brace-init](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)) quity easily.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec{ { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };

    std::cout << "vec size = " << vec.size() << "x" << vec[0].size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
vec size = 3x2
```